# commandButton in Primefaces dialog triggers action only on subsequent clicks

Tags: primefaces, modal-dialog, commandbutton

I ran into a bit of a problem with *Primefaces* `dialog` and the `actionListener` on my `commandButton`.

*To provide a bit of backdrop:*
The application I maintain currently uses an older version of *ICEfaces*. I've been tasked to find out if replacing it with a current version of *Primefaces* (I'm currently using **5.2.6**) would provide benefits in terms of speed/reaction time and also what we would need to do, to replace the framework. We have to do this with the minimum amount of work and so rebuilding all our pop-ups is kind of out of the question.

*Now, to the problem at hand:*
I'm trying to replace the old `ace:dialog` with `p:dialog` and so far it was as easy as just switching out the tags. The dialogs work almost as before but I have a weird problem with the `h:commandButton`.
I picked out one of the pop-ups, which is used to display error messages, to work on a proof of concept. I know that other pop-ups suffer from the same problem however. Here is the code for this pop-up, which I stripped down to the bare necessities.

```
<ui:composition xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<p:dialog id="ErrorPopupID" widgetVar="panelPopupErrorWidget" 
    position="center" modal="true" resizable="false" draggable="false" 
    closeOnEscape="false" header="Errors"
    visible="#{errorPopupBean.renderErrorPopup}">
        <h:panelGroup style="width:320px;">
            <div style="height:218px;padding:5px;">
                <h:outputText escape="false" value="Error text"/>
            </div>
                <h:form>
                <div style="padding-left:5px;">
                    <h:commandButton id="errorPopupCloseButton"
                     value="Close"
                     actionListener="#{errorPopupBean.closeErrorPopup}"/>
                </div>
            </h:form>
        </h:panelGroup>
</p:dialog>
```

As you can see the pop-up contains a button that basically just closes the pop-up and also clears the message list. For a reason I can not figure out, the action is only triggered when I click the button a second time. When I click it for the first time, nothing seems to happen from the users point of view.
I happen to have a `PhaseListener` however, so I know that upon the first click a request is send to the server, but that only phases 1 and 6 of the life-cycle are executed. Only on the second click the entire life-cycle - including `INVOKE_APPLICATION` - is processed and the action fires. But I can't figure out why.

Here is what I've tried without success:

- replaced `h:commandButton` with `p:commandButton`
- tried different nesting of the `h:form` (was originally outside of `p:dialog`)
- moved the `ui:include` for the pop-up directly in front of `</h:body>`
- tried both `FULL` and `PARTIAL` for `primefaces.SUBMIT`
- various variations of all of the above
- **EDIT:** I also tried three different versions of *Primefaces*, *4.0.10* and *5.0.10* in addition to the *5.2.6* I'm actually using, just to see if it was a glitch in this particular version of PF.

I'm at a loss here and don't know what else to try. It worked with *ICEfaces* so I think it must work with *Primefaces* too.
I checked the other questions here as well, but they either deal with a different scenario or `p:dialog` not working at all. Mine works, but just not exactly right.

Comment: How is the dialog closed? With javascript in the backing bean? Try `<p:commandButton id="errorPopupCloseButton"
                     value="Close"
                     actionListener="#{errorPopupBean.closeErrorPopup}"/> oncomplete="PF('panelPopupErrorWidget').hide()">`

Comment: @opfau The value of the dialogs `visibility` attribute is determined by the bean. Which means the action method just clears a list and then `errorPopupBean.renderErrorPopup` returns false. This works and is not the problem however. The pop-up closes as expected. The problem is that the action event is only triggered on the second click on the button, not on the first. I can clearly see that in the debugger and `PhaseListener` output.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try **p**:commandButton with attribute **ajax="false"**.

Comment: Changed it to `<p:commandButton id="errorPopupCloseButton" value="Close" ajax="false" actionListener="#{errorPopupBean.closeErrorPopup}"/>` but nothing changed. The behavior is still the same.